# How to stop multiple android services in a List of services that use MediaPlayer to play many songs simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-service-binding

Hey guys sorry if this has been asked before but I have been reading other answers and documentation for more than 3 hours with no success, I really can't find how to solve this problem.

### Description

So I have this List:

`private List<MusicService> songList;`

And adding to it all my needed services:

```
private Intent rainIntent;
private Intent stormIntent;
private Intent oceanIntent;
```

Then I initialize them:

```
    rainIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    stormIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    oceanIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
```

Then I pass them the ID of songs I want to play `onStartCommand()`

```
    rainIntent.putExtra(MusicService.SONG_ID, R.raw.rain);
    songsIntentsList.add(rainIntent);
    stormIntent.putExtra(MusicService.SONG_ID, R.raw.thunder);
    songsIntentsList.add(stormIntent);
    oceanIntent.putExtra(MusicService.SONG_ID, R.raw.ocean);
    songsIntentsList.add(oceanIntent);
```

When I use the list to start all services there's no problem, this works fine:

```
private void startSongsServices() {

    for (Intent intent : songsIntentsList) {
        context.startService(intent);
    }

}
```

## My problem:

But when trying to use stopService() it doesn't work what can I do? Just like the following:

```
private void stopSongsServices() {

    for (Intent intent : songsIntentsList) {
        context.stopService(intent);
    }

}
```

This is the class for `MusicService`:

```
public class MusicService extends Service {


    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public static String SONG_ID = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int id = intent.getExtras().getInt(SONG_ID);

        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,id);


        if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();

        }

        return START_STICKY; //START_STICKY makes service run until we call onDestroy() service to stop it
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

How can I stop all this services when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onDestroy will be called only once.

You need to keep track of media player objects you are creating and stop them in a loop.Right now you are creating 3 mediaplayer objects(onStartCommand is getting called 3 times) but releasing only one.

Something like below

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    int id = intent.getExtras().getInt(SONG_ID);

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,id);
    mediaPlayerObjectsList.add(mMediaPlayer);
}
```

Then in `onDestroy()` do something like this:

```
  for (MediaPlayer player : mediaPlayerObjectsList) {
        player.release();
    }
```

Comment: thanks you so much for kind explanation I used instead a set so when adding songs they don't repeat and onStartCommand: `for (MediaPlayer player : mMediaPlayerSet){
            if (player != null) {
                player.start();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I stop all this services when needed?

You only have one service. Services are natural singletons. Your three `startService()` calls resulted in one instance of `MusicService`. The first `startService()` call would have created the instance (and `onCreate()` would be called), and the other two `startService()` calls would just have sent commands to the running service instance. So, `onStartCommand()` would be called three times on that one instance, and so you created three instances of a `MediaPlayer`... and only retained a reference to the last one.

If you want to have one `MediaPlayer` instance per command, you are welcome to do so, but you need to hold onto *all* of them, so you can clean up *all* of them in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: How should I "hold" the instances for the different `MediaPlayer`s?

Comment: @cooervo: `List<MediaPlayer>`, presumably.